# Colour a vector file based on colour data in a field

Tags: qgis, color

I have a geological units shapefile which has colour data in a field, in which the colour data relates to an associated text and will help in clarifying which unit is which down the line. 
An example is:
"BASECOLOUR" !FIELD NAME 
"40, 15, 5, 0" !FIELD DATA

I assume these are CMYK values?

So, how can I do it?
Can I build a rule-based expression which uses the field to define the CMYK values?

Comment: If you can extract each value of cyan, magenta, yellow, black to each corresponding attribute field, you can style it by expression. On the `Layer Properties | Style` tab, click on `Data defined override` (big epsilon button) next to `Colors` and Edit to give an expression `color_cmyk("cyan", "magenta", "yellow", "black")`.

Comment: I will try to extract the data into different fields, any advice on that? ALSO i do not have a data defined overide button, however i can click the large epsilon (which causes a feature count)... i can still create a rule using the color_cmyk expression so that should work...

Comment: Extracting and splitting the text into c,m,y,k value would be tricky part. I myself would go with Excel 'Text to Columns' function but there may be better ways.

Comment: @Simon, the example you posted is the content of only one field? I mean, `!FIELD NAME "40, 15, 5, 0" !FIELD DATA` is entirely stored in the "BASECOLOUR" field? I feel I'm wrong. Can you please attach only the content stored in the field for defining the colors?

Comment: hi mgri, yes the field name is BASECOLOUR, and the example of the data contained in the field was 40,15,5,0.

Comment: @Kazuhito i cannot use your technique. How can i create a colour ramp using the colour data fields? The classification category will not be the colour field... it would be something else, such as Main_Rock (which contains data like sandstone or mud).  I am having a little trouble with this... For example when i classify the data by Main rock it creates an individual rule where Main_rock = "sandstone" it will use a set colour, however how do i group them all and get them to use the cmyk colours...

Comment: So the color was stored in BASECOLOUR field and numbers "40, 15, 5, 0" was not CMYK set, I understood. Sorry I could not be of any help. I suspect these numbers might be related to color ramp algorithms (e.g. HSV) but not sure.

Comment: @kazuhito, thank you, you did help! Yes the Basecolour data is cmyk data, but i ran into a problem.. i do not know how to classify my data using one field (e.g. Rock type), but colourise the classification i make using another (e.g. basecolour). The colour_cmyk command worked and turned the cmyk data into RGB data. But i do not know how to use these expressions to modify the classification colour ramp...

Comment: @Simon If I understand you are trying to categorize symbol by one field (Rock Type) and colored by another field (BASECOLOUR) then you can use `Rule-based` styling for symbol and refine its rule by adding categories for Fill Colors. (Rules can be nested.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse the CMYK values you can setup a custom function in the Expression Builder and use it to extract the values into individual fields.

1. When looking at the attribute table click on the expression builder.

[image]

2. Click on the Function Editor tab and add a function to parse the color field.  Click the "Load" button to "save/enable" it.

   ```
   def getColorComponent(color, num, feature, parent):
       items = color.split(',')
       return int(items[num])
   ```
3. Use the new custom function to parse out one of the individual CMYK components and save it in a new field.  Color values are zero indexed so in the example the 4th value is being stored in the black field with  getColorComponent(  "color" , 3).

Hope this helps with part of the problem.  The good thing is you've got the colors as attributes.

Comment: Thanks cokrzys, this worked wonderfully. Of course i did not think at first that color was the name of my colour field so that took several minutes before i clicked. my colours are stored in the field "BASECOLOUR".